# O consumo de memória de uma variável aumenta cada vez que é utilizada?

Tags: php, variáveis, memória

Tenho tentando entender mais sobre o consumo de memória das variáveis criadas. E fiz até alguns testes aqui no meu computador com variáveis! Criei então algumas variáveis e a utilizei varias vezes. Notei que o consumo de memoria - medido em bytes - não teve nenhuma mudança.

Ao criar uma `$variavel` o uso de memoria relacionado a ela é contabilizado apenas na hora de criação - considerando então que uma pequena de quantia de memoria foi alocada para essa variável, sendo assim as variáveis idênticas a ela virão da memoria alocada anteriormente- ou cada vez que uso ela é alocado mais um pouco de memoria?

Vale ressaltar que minha dúvida aqui não é a quantidade de memória que a variável usa, e sim se ela usa memória a cada vez que for utilizada ou se é utilizada um pouco de memória apenas na hora da criação, fazendo com que as seguintes reutilizações da mesma variável seja um "reflexo" da memoria alocada anteriormente.

Comment: Isso é extremamente relativo a utilização do código, dependendo do caso, você pode criar diversas variáveis que faças diversas operações, se as mesmas não tiverem uma finalidade (uma escrita de qualquer natureza) elas se quer inicializadas, o copilador tem diversas rotinas de otimização, se você quer entender como funciona a alocação de memoria pelas variáveis veja como funciona no C, é bem intuitivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Não é fácil medir

Em PHP o consumo de memória não é tão fácil de acompanhar assim. Não é simples monitorar o consumo. Você não informou como o fez mas provavelmente usou algum método "ingênuo" que não considera todo o funcionamento ([`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) e outras funções do gênero que dão uma informação pouco confiável (olhar o que o sistema operacional diz é pior ainda). Eu poderia falar mais sobre os testes feitos se eles tivessem sido postados.

Eu não sei dar detalhes mas muito provavelmente o PHP já começa alocando certos espaços para utilização do *script*. **Alocar é diferente de armazenar algum valor**. Então pode ser que "criar" variáveis em um primeiro momento não afete nada o consumo de memória já alocado inicialmente. Não dá para fazer uma avaliação direta de consumo com facilidade.

De qualquer forma uma **[variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é apenas um nome para acessar uma posição de memória**. O consumo de memória dessa posição é contabilizado enquanto tiver um dado relevante referenciado por essa variável. Até mesmo se a variável deixar de existir. Há variáveis que são donas do conteúdo por ela apontado/contido, mas nem sempre.

## Várias formas de alocação

Até onde eu sei não ocorre com o PHP na maioria das situações, mas é possível uma variável gerar diversas alocações diferentes que permanecem vivas mesmo não havendo mais utilidade de versões diferentes anteriores.

Algumas variáveis ditas "por valor" têm um consumo em um local apenas, outras ditas "por referência" possuem um local que aponta para outro local onde realmente está seu conteúdo. E obviamente seu conteúdo pode ser outro apontamento. Leve isto em consideração.

Você fala em "utilizar" as variáveis. Dependendo do que é, este "utilizar" não vai fazer diferença. Pegar seu valor obviamente não afeta alocação. Mudar seu valor pode afetar se a variável é considerada imutável ou pelo menos se tiver um novo valor que ocupe mais espaço que o previamente alocado, mas isso pode não ser verdade e usar o mesmo local.

Então trocar `1` por `2` em uma variável não vai afetar nada o consumo de memória. Já trocar uma *string* de 20 caracteres por outra de 200 vai afetar. Me parece óbvio, né?

Já reduzir a *string* de 200 para 20 caracteres pode liberar alguma memória imediatamente, mas é mais provável que isto não seja feito, você pode precisar usar de novo logo em seguida.

Quando você aumenta o tamanho da *string* no exemplo acima o PHP poderia fazer uma nova alocação para os 180 caracteres e aproveitar os 20 já alocados. Mas é provável que haverá uma alocação extra além do necessário para evitar novas realocações futuras. Tem várias otimizações que podem ser aplicadas, na maioria dos casos isto não é importante para o programador. Está vendo como vai tendo casos que tornam difícil acompanhar o real consumo?

O mais comum é o PHP reaproveitar o máximo que dá quando um valor muda. Não é característica da linguagem fazer realocações desnecessárias.

Mas não confunda variável com seu valor. E não confunda o valor real da variável com o objeto apontado pela variável nos casos que a variável guarda uma referência para o objeto.

Todas as vezes que você joga um valor de uma variável para outra variável, mesmo que seja através da passagem de parâmetros você está copiando o valor de uma variável para outra. Como você tem outra variável, é claro que há uma nova alocação. Mas essas variáveis podem estar um uma área chamada [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), e já estar tudo alocado.

Mas note que os tipos mais complexos, por referência, esse valor é apenas um ponteiro representado por um endereço de memória. E o dado real que interessa está em um outro objeto apontado por essa referência que é copiada. Não há cópia do objeto complexo, exemplos são o *array* ou uma *string*. Como há a cópia da referência então pode haver mais de uma variável segurando referências para o mesmo objeto. Portanto o objeto não pode ser liberado enquanto há uma referência para ele. O fato de liberar uma variável, não significa que o objeto apontado por ela será liberado.

A cópia do objeto ocorre em casos mais raros.

## Conclusão

Eu realmente não sei como é a implementação atual do PHP (isto é um detalhe que pode mudar por uma série de razões) e não lembro bem como era no passado quando eu pesquisei.

Tem pouca informação sobre isso e poucas pessoas estão interessadas. Sabe por que? Porque em PHP isto não costuma ser relevante. Se o consumo de memória for relevante para sua aplicação provavelmente está usando a linguagem errada. Não estou dizendo que não deva ser curioso e pesquisar sobre o assunto, apenas que para o uso normal essa preocupação não é necessária.

Notou também como é difícil avaliar o consumo de memória de forma precisa? Nem há ferramentas que ajudam muito já que não costuma ser relevante medir isto nessa linguagem.

Não totalmente relacionado com o PHP porque ele funciona de um jeito um pouco diferente, mas conhecer a [*stack* e o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) ajuda entender o consumo de memória.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

A resposta para sua pergunta é **não**, se você define uma variável ela aloca um espaço na memoria, esse espaço vai ser utilizado ate que o famoso [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php) ache necessário liberar espaço.

> Lembrando que você pode utilizar o unset() para liberar o espaço
>   alocado

No php você pode apontar duas variaveis para a mesma referencia dessa forma

```
<?php
    $var;
    $a = 2;
    $a =& $var;
?>
```

Qualquer modificação em $a ou $b causa modificação mutua, veja a ilustração
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Veja esse artigo sobre variáveis no PHP](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf)

Acredito que sua duvida seja fruto de uma confusão entre memoria X processador

### Como funciona a memoria (básico)

A memoria é basicamente é um conjunto de espaços alocados e endereçados,
qualquer variável é apontada para um desses espaços, porem você deve levar em consideração que o php não trabalha diretamente na memoria, assim como nenhum programa que rode em algum sistema operacional linux/windows/etc, pois os mesmos implementam uma [técnica de memoria virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). o que pode ser gasto a cada acesso a memoria seria processamento e não memoria, para entender isso é necessário entender como o processador funciona

### Como funciona o processador (básico)

Abstraindo ao máximo o processador, podemos dizer que ele movimenta blocos usando regras (comandos) para essa finalidade, qualquer operação de leitura ou escrita passa pelo processador para ser realizada, salvo algumas operações de entrada de dados que são controlados pela controladora. resumindo para cada acesso a variável o processador pega o endereço dessa variável e joga o conteúdo dela em algum registrador.

### No PHP é diferente

Devemos lembrar que o responsável pelo gerenciamento de memoria, alocação de endereços ou quais quer operações com o sistema são feitas pelo interpretador, então você não tem esse controle, você não sabe quantos acessos vão ser feitos ou o mecanismo de cache implementado por ele, então isso fica bem real ativo.